# Symfony map form fields

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm rewriting old deprecated REST API on Symfony and problem is how to map and validate fields with different names on Symfony form.

An example I have Symfony form, with fields:

```
->add('receiverCity', TextType::class, ['constraints' => new NotBlank()])
->add('receiverCountry', TextType::class, ['constraints' => new NotBlank()])
->add('receiverPostCode', TextType::class, ['constraints' => new NotBlank()])
```

and in Controller from request I get same fields with different names like:

```
$data = ['city' => 'My city', 'country' => 'My country', 'postal' => 'My post code'];
```

Then I submit form manually $form->submit($data). And question is what is the best way to map and validate this field in form? Should I use form events or there is a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `property_path` option. (Also see [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path) for more information).

You would need to use the "old" field names as form field names and set the `property_path` to the actual field name within the object:

```php
->add('city', TextType::class, 
    [
        'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
        'property_path' => 'receiverCity'
    ]
)
->add('country', TextType::class,
    [
        'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
        'property_path' => 'receiverCountry'
    ]
)
->add('postal', TextType::class, 
    [
        'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
        'property_path' => 'receiverPostCode'
    ]
)
```